# what 3D shape can be used to make any 3D shape when combined With itself?

Tags: three-dimensional

Looking to create a puzzle / representation of any 3D shape using smaller 3D shape. Is there some sort of shape / ultimate 3D shape that can make any other 3D shape. Like a pyramid or sphere or cube or something?

Comment: With an infinite supply of "points", you can construct any 3-d shape. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*No.*

Shapes with different [Dehn invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_invariant) cannot be dissected into one another no matter how you cut them up, whether into identical or different pieces. Two simple shapes that cannot be dissected into one another are a regular tetrahedron and a cube.

If there were a shape like you asked, you could construct a dissection from a cube to a regular tetrahedron.

Also, this question would seem to fit better on Mathematics Stack Exchange, just so you know.